# GTMetrix Wordpress Speed issue

Tags: wordpress, performance, seo, gtmetrix

I am trying to reduce the load time for my website using GTMetrix. I find below references from my site. But I am not able to find the source.

I checked themes and plugins as well and came to conclusion its some unwanted code or spam.

```
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11122200772940/browser_features1488235112.js
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11122200773193/atlas_tots1480453070.js
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237204735744/PerspectiveTransform.min.js
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237204735744/banner.js
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237204735744/bannerboy.min.js
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237204735744/content.jpg
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237204735744/cta_txt.png
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237204735744/image_1.jpg
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237204735744/image_2.png
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237204735744/logo_squarespace.png
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237204735744/settings.js
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237204735744/txt_0_1.png
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237204735744/txt_0_2.png
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237204735744/txt_0_3.png
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237204735744/txt_1_1.png
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237204735744/txt_2_1.png
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237205062003/GothamSSm-Book.woff
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237205062003/GothamSSm-Light.woff
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237205062003/banner.min.js
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237205062003/bg.jpg
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237205062003/bg_blurred.jpg
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237205062003/handPointer.png
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237205062003/icon_cart.png
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237205062003/icon_check.png
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237205062003/icon_close.png
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237205062003/logo_squarespace.png
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237205062003/mousePointer.png
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237205062003/txt_cta.png
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237205062003/txt_cta_hover.png
https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11237205062003/txt_endframe.png
```

https://gtmetrix.com/reports/projectsgeek.com/G3QsoTpO

Please help

Comment: looks like a malware https://www.google.co.in/search?q=cdn%20atlassbx

Answer (score 0):

For wordpress and speed you need to install a cache plugin like wp total cache, also you need to enable G-zip compression server side